# How can I solve the error concerning libogg

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <assert.h>  
#include <fstream>  
#include <map>  
#include <ostream>  
#include "ogg.h"  
using namespace std;  
#pragma comment(lib,"libogg.lib")enter code hereenter
void readogg();
void readogg(){

    ifstream stream;
    ifstream file("invitation.ogg", ios::in | ios::binary);
    ogg_sync_state state;
    ogg_sync_init(&state);

    ogg_page page;
    if (ogg_sync_pageout(&state, &page) != 1)
    {
        char* buffer = ogg_sync_buffer(&state, 8092);
        assert(buffer);
        file.read(buffer, 8092);
        int bytes = stream.gcount();
        ogg_sync_wrote(&state, bytes);
    }
    ogg_stream_state s_state;
    ogg_packet pack;

    ☆ ogg_stream_pagein(&s_state, &page);
    ogg_page_packets(&page);
    ogg_stream_packetout(&s_state, &pack);
}
```

This is my code what I was invisible mending. I have another code about main but it have not a problem. I debugged step by step, so I think ☆ code might have a error and the result might do not connects or saves information of 'invitation.ogg' file.

I couldn't find answer anywhere and this is my final chance keeping on this code. I'm not Thanks to read my question and I really hope to find my answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It'd be great if you could show what you've done to attempt to solve the issue or work out what's gone wrong - this shows the community that you've put some effort into it and also will help them to see what's wrong and solve the issue more quickly.  Thanks!

Comment: could you paste the exact error you're getting? Is it a compilation problem? A segmentation fault?... We can't read in your mind or on your computer screen, you have to give more relevant details if you want help.